# How to use actual text over SVG image and make its place fixed?

Tags: html, css

I have 9 boxes in my Wordpress website and I built them with svg images ([**Link**](http://barandigitaldentistry.com/services/)). Even texts are not actual texts. I want to rebuild the boxes and use actual texts in each box. Obviously, I want to place the text in a way that doesn't change in any screen size, Using **custom CSS**.

I only could build the blue rectangular button with actual text and couldn't build the text part and discount label with actual texts (see the link above).

[image: I want to rebuild this with actual texts]

Generally speaking, I want to know how can I position something **depend** on another element. In this case the texts' positions would be depended on other parts of the box. The texts should preserve their position and shape in every screen size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add these styles to your `div.ServicesPageBox`

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Then wrap the svg inside that `div.ServicesPageBox` with another `div` and set these styles to that `div`

```
position: relative;
```

Next put your text inside that `div` and make them

```
position: absolute;
```

Then control the position of text with `top` and `left`. The position of text is now relative to the svg.
You can also add `z-index: 10;` to your text to make sure that's on top of `svg`

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your code would help diagnose the issue... one thought I have is using z-indices (give the text a z-index of 10 and the images a z-index of 0, then % or em or fr spacing options to align them accordingly.

Comment: It's all SVG code that built this box. It's literally an image. I want to use actual text.

Comment: Ok, There is actually no z-index for svgs. But svg determines which of your elements are the uppermost by theire position in the DOM. Thus you can remove the Object (text) and place it to the end of the svg making it the "last rendered" element.

Comment: perhaps if that doesn't work, checkout this github solution:
https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/252

Comment: Sorry to foget to mention. I have to place the texts independetly, not in SVG file. Because, You know, the Persian script doesn't render properly in SVG. I had converted the texts to shape (using "create outlines" option in adobe illiustrator). So, If it was Latin script, I guess it was easier. @jon-christie

Comment: ah gothca... no worries man. Its all a learning experience either way. Hope you get it sorted out. GL